# Delete observations outside of a range (in R or Stata)

Tags: r, stata

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), month = c(201701, 201702, 
201703, 201704, 201705, 201706, 201707, 201708, 201809, 201810, 
201811, 201812, 201901, 201902, 201903, 201705, 201706, 201707, 
201708, 201709, 201710, 201711, 201712, 201801, 201809), dummy = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L))
```

For each id, I would like to delete all observations outside a seven observations window around the dummy that equals one.

In short, I want to keep the observation for which the dummy equals "1" and three observations before as well as three after.

The expected outcome should be:

```
> print(df1, n = 22)
# A tibble: 21 × 3
      id  month dummy
   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 201701     0
 2     1 201702     0
 3     1 201703     0
 4     1 201704     1
 5     1 201705     0
 6     1 201706     0
 7     1 201707     0
 8     2 201809     0
 9     2 201810     0
10     2 201811     0
11     2 201812     1
12     2 201901     0
13     2 201902     0
14     2 201903     0
15     3 201707     0
16     3 201708     0
17     3 201709     0
18     3 201710     1
19     3 201711     0
20     3 201712     0
21     3 201801     0
```

In Stata, I can't download any program.
Stata example:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input byte id long month byte dummy float mdate
1 201701 0 684
1 201702 0 685
1 201703 0 686
1 201704 1 687
1 201705 0 688
1 201706 0 689
1 201707 0 690
1 201708 0 691
2 201809 0 704
2 201810 0 705
2 201811 0 706
2 201812 1 707
2 201901 0 708
2 201902 0 709
2 201903 0 710
3 201705 0 688
3 201706 0 689
3 201707 0 690
3 201708 0 691
3 201709 0 692
3 201710 1 693
3 201711 0 694
3 201712 0 695
3 201801 0 696
3 201809 0 704
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is only one `dummy == 1` per id, this can easily be solved by:

```
library(dplyr) #version>= 1.1.0
df %>%
  filter(abs(row_number() - which(dummy>0))<=3, .by=id)

# A tibble: 21 × 3
      id  month dummy
   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 201701     0
 2     1 201702     0
 3     1 201703     0
 4     1 201704     1
 5     1 201705     0
 6     1 201706     0
 7     1 201707     0
 8     2 201809     0
 9     2 201810     0
10     2 201811     0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you have a solution for dplyr < 1.1.0?
I do not have access to the new version in my computer.

Comment: @Rnovice use `df %>%group_by(id) %>% filter(abs(row_number() - which(dummy>0))<=3)`

Answer (score 1):

In Stata

```
bysort id (mdate) : gen t = _n
tsset id t 

keep if dummy | inlist(1, F3.dummy, F2.dummy, F1.dummy, L1.dummy, L2.dummy, L3.dummy)
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `match/between`

```
library(dplyr)
 df1 %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   filter(between(row_number() - match(1, dummy), -3, 3)) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 21 × 3
      id  month dummy
   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 201701     0
 2     1 201702     0
 3     1 201703     0
 4     1 201704     1
 5     1 201705     0
 6     1 201706     0
 7     1 201707     0
 8     2 201809     0
 9     2 201810     0
10     2 201811     0
# … with 11 more rows
```